# php order by 'most recent' 'most liked' 'least like'

Tags: php

I have a post system in place

```
    <?php
/**
Display the results from the database
**/
$q = ("SELECT * FROM threads ORDER BY posted");
$r = mysql_query($q);

if(mysql_num_rows($r)>0): //table is non-empty
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)):
        $net_vote = $row['votes_up'] - $row['votes_down']; //this is the net result of voting up and voting down
?>
<div class='entry'>
    <span class='link'>
        <?php echo $row['author']; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <?php $row['posted'] = date("jS M Y h:i",$row['posted']); echo $row['posted']; ?>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="horizontal" data-text="<?php echo $row['message']; ?>">
        Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
        <br/> 
        <div class='message'><?php echo $row['message']; ?><br/></div> 
            <?php echo "<a href='msg.php?id=$row[id]'/> Comments/Add comments $row[replies]</a>" ?> &nbsp;
        <?php echo "Likes: " . $row['votes_up'] . "&nbsp "; echo "Dislikes: " . $row['votes_down'] . "&nbsp"; ?>    
    </span>

    <span class='votes_count' id='votes_count<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'></span> 
    <span class='vote_buttons' id='vote_buttons<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>
        <a href='javascript:;' class='vote_up' id='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'></a>
        <a href='javascript:;' class='vote_down' id='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'></a>

    <br/>
    </span>

</div>

<br/>
<?php
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

I want to add text that says 'order by : Most recent | Most liked | least liked '
As you can see i think ive got it already posting most recent by defualt which is what i want.
But what i want also is when you click 'Most liked' & 'least liked' it sorts by 'Vote_up' ( likes) & 'vote_down' (dislikes) all on the same page and shows posts with most likes on them (most liked) and most dislike (least liked)

EDIT*****
sorry my question is how can i add 2 functions that when on click sorts by 'most liked' and 'least liked'

Comment: edited with question. I thought it was clear but ive explained more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in html:

```
<a href='script.php?order=recent'>Recent</a>
<a href='script.php?order=liked'>Liked</a>
...
```

in php:

```
if ($_GET['order'] == 'recent') $order = "posted";
elseif ($_GET['order'] == 'liked') $order = "smth";
...
$q = "SELECT * FROM threads ORDER BY ".$order."";
```

but actually it's better to use some js framework (i prefer [extjs](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/) for that) to sort the output on client side

Comment: 2 'Notice: Undefined index' on 278 which is the 'if ($_get['order']...etc' line you gave me and 'Undefined variable' on the same line. And when clicking the link it gives 'object not found' error page

Comment: it's obvious that you have to change `script.php` to the name of your script!

Comment: yes i noticed and changed this just after i posted.. But when i first click the page it displays all the errors and them when i click recent it goes back to normal and good and then when i click liked it displays error : Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: i don't know your table structure. `$order = "smth";` is meant to be replaced with the field you want to order by.

Comment: @louismoore18 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1355/discussion-between-k102-and-louismoore18)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you have few choices how to do this:

1. Have the links pass a $_GET value via URL (causes a page refresh!!), then test for this in the PHP and run the necessary SQL to get the new record order.
2. Use AJAX to perform the same request asynchronously, with a PHP script to handle the SQL function and return the desired results.
3. Use a jQuery plugin such as [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) to (probably) basically provide the same functionality as that in 2, or via it's own filtering system -- I'm not sure i've not used it!!

My preference would be 1. (i.e a pure PHP + MySQL solution) as this offers the best universal functionality. You could always add javascript / ajax later to make things more swish for more modern browsers and users!

Comment: could you provide a example for option 1